# Display child component in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I currently have a parent component that has it own route

`<route path="/parent" component={parent} />`

but I am wondering how I can display a child component in there when the child component has its own route.

`<route path="/child" component={parent} />`

When the route above gets hit, I still want to send out the same parent component but have a child component render in the parent component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   render () {

     //Render Child component if route is there
     <Child />
   }
}
```

I am aware I can have the `<route>` component nested in the parent component, but I rather not do it this way.

Comment: take a look at this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar im pretty sure it is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

```
<route path="/parent" render={ (props) => <parent><child /></parent> } />
```